# ASP.NET MVC 4 Bundles giving 404 error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, umbraco6, system.web.optimization

I want to add Bundles into an existing ASP.NET MVC 4 (.NET 4.5) website that uses:

- Umbraco 6.1.5
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.1.3 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization/)

I attempted to follow these directions: https://gist.github.com/jkarsrud/5143239, and the CSS loaded fine before I started down the bundles path.

On page load it inserts the style reference:

```
<link href="/bundles/marketingcss" rel="stylesheet">
```

But a 404 error happens:

```
> GET http://localhost:20459/bundles/marketingcss 404 (Not Found)
```

Here's what I've in code:

**Web.Config**

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/bundles" />
```

**Global.asax**

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MapCom.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using Umbraco.Web;

namespace MapCom
{
    public class Global : UmbracoApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnApplicationStarted(sender, e);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/marketingcss");
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace MapCom
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
            ///
            ///Marketing Site CSS Bundle
            ///
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/marketingcss")
                .Include("~/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css")
                .Include("~/css/font-awesome.min.css")
                .Include("~/plugins/parallax-slider/css/parallax-slider.css")
                .Include("~/css/combinedStyles.min.css")
                .Include("~/plugins/ladda-buttons/css/ladda.min.css")
                .Include("~/plugins/ladda-buttons/css/custom-lada-btn.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if it still applies, but it at least *used* to be that bundling wouldn't work at all if you included files with ".min" in the filename. The output seems to indicate that `Styles.Render` thinks you're pointing to an actual file rather than a bundle - since otherwise, it would include a version query parameter when `EnableOptimizations` is on - i.e. `/bundles/marketingcss?v=...`.

Comment: @JimmiTh that did help to fix some of the errors that were evident in the bundle after I got it going. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much digging into Umbraco, I noticed that the project I'm working on is utilizing a class:

```
 public class ApplicationEventHandler : IApplicationEventHandler
```

Which is explained in more detail here: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Events/application-startup

But the gist is:

> In order to bind to certain events in the Umbraco application you need to make these registrations during application startup. Based on the Umbraco version you are using there are various ways to hook in to the application starting. The higher the version you are using the more robust this becomes.

So Umbraco's overriding some of the ASP.NET start-up methods.

I solved my issue by adding a reference to System.Web.Optimization in ApplicationEventHandler.cs and moved my bundle registration to this method in that class:

```
public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Comment: Umbraco is overriding a lot of ASP.NET features like: Membership (UmbracoMembershipProvider), current thread : http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/11342-Umbraco-overriding-SystemThreadingThreadCurrentThreadCurrentCulture and other more. Just think at this "problem" from now on

Comment: either putting the call in `OnApplicationStarting` or `OnApplicationStarted` work for me once I had updated the web.config (see my answer)

Comment: i had the same issue to access font awesome fonts, for **other solutions**  try these links which deals with `StyleBundle` **virtualpath**: [Link 1](http://www.mvccentral.net/story/details/articles/kahanu/stylebundle-403-error-solved) , [Link 2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1774324.aspx?MVC4+css+bundling+and+image+references), [Link 3](http://ericpanorel.net/2013/10/25/font-awesome-4-0-mvc-bundling-and-minification/), [Link 4](http://jameschambers.com/2014/08/adding-some-font-awesome-to-mvc-and-bootstrap/) , hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

The **ONLY** thing that worked for me here was adding the path to the bundle to the following setting in `web.config`

**My bundle Code**

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/opt/jscripts").Include(
                "~/Scripts/twitterFetcher.js"
                ));
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

**Umbraco default setting**

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/" />
```

**New setting**

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/opt/" />
```

Comment: Right -- you definitely need to add the reserved path, otherwise Umbraco routing will try and handle that instead of letting .NET handle it.

Answer (score 2):

try the following suggestions:

1.Do not use keyword **bundles** for your **css** virtual path so just change it to something else, and use the keyword *bundles* for your scripts only.
like this:

> ```
>  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/marketingcss")
> ```

(**Remember** you need to make sure that if you have a file called marketingcss under content folder you should change the virtual path to something else, so the virtual path shouldn't duplicate the physical path)

2.in your _Layout.cshtml use the following line instead of yours:

> ```
>  @Styles.Render(BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/marketingcss"))
> ```

3.if the above suggestions didn't work then try this one in your _Layout.cshtml instead:

> ```
> <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.
>                Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/marketingcss")"
>                rel="stylesheet"
>                type="text/css" />
> ```

**updated**

4.just saw one of our friend's comment about not to putting .min files in your bundle, which is correct so you must not include .min files in your budleConfig class, and just use the normal files like `bootstarp.css` instead of `bootstrap.min.css` and do the same for all other files, of course make sure you have the normal files first so not just change the names.

I hope it helps to fix your code

Comment: Unfortunately none of those items helped -- determined it was an Umbraco technicality causing the issue.

Comment: @cvocvo Could you please elaborate on the Umbraco technicality, I think i am having the same issues as you